# Rest full web service API url is changed in d8

Tags: 8

I have rest service url for a node in d6  as

```
https://192.168.1.236/rest_endpoint/node/1140.json
```

but the same url in drupal 8 is not working at all , for d8 i have  to give

```
https://192.168.1.236/rest_endpoint/node/1140?_format=json
```

here **1140 is the node id** and **192.168.1.236 is the base url** .

As the url is changing i have to modify many scripts .What may be the reason for this ? or is there any workarounds ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [related issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2501221):

> Drupal core no longer uses accept headers for routing but rather rely on a _format query parameter, **because browser, (reverse) proxy and CDN support is very poor, and hence could lead to severe bugs**. See [See #2364011: [meta] External caches mix up response formats on URLs where content negotiation is in use](https://www.drupal.org/node/2364011) for more background.

So it was a conscious decision, to help prevent common bugs out in the wild. I wouldn't advise trying to find a workaround, the motivation for changing it is sound. But if you want/need to, perhaps just a simple rewrite rule that would take requests for `*.json` and forward them on to `*?_format=json` would suffice.

Comment: thanks , probably redirection without changing the url with htaccess would work ?

Comment: Can't think of a reason it wouldn't, it'd definitely save you a lot of work